# Creating a colour variable in SCSS using another colour variable

Tags: css, colors, sass

I am fairly new to SCSS. But I am setting up a starter toolkit for myself for all my projects and have come across an issue I'm not quite sure how to search for in Google so thought I would post here.

Basically I have a color variable called $main-color for example. I want to then be able to setup variables that our tints of this main color.

I have the following, but it is throwing errors.

```
$70-main: lighten($main-color, 30%);
```

I was hoping that this would lighten my main color by 30%.

Could anybody with more knowledge of SCSS than me provide a solution for this.

Thanks

Da

Comment: You can't have numbers as the first characters of a variable name ( not sure why, perhaps someone else can expand on it ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost correct. Variables cannot start with numbers:

```
$main-70: lighten($main-color,30%);
```

Comment: Perfect, Thank you for the help.